# Model structure in many to many relationship without ORM

Tags: java

I have two tables: User(id pk, name, ...) and Exercise(id pk, content, ...) which have many-to-many relationship. I create two classes representing its.

```
public class User{
    private int id;
    private String name;
    ....
}

public class Exercise{
    private int id;
    private String content;
    ....
}
```

So, my question is how to add many-to-many relationship without using any ORM(don't ask me why i can't do it)? Is it normal to create new class UserExercise like:

```
public class UserExercise{
    private int id_user;
    private int id_exercise;
}
```

Answer of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14219954/model-structure-in-many-to-many-relationship) article is about using ORM, and it doesn't suit me

PS: Sorry for my english.

Comment: A class is not a database table. You should model your classes thinking in the domain not in the data

Comment: @Hector and how it must work? For example, adding in User additional field 'List<Exercise> exercises' and same in Exercise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you have specific attribute on the relationship itself, you will not have a class to map the relationship.

You also have to determine the navigability of the association user-exercise. Is it bi- or uni-directional ? I.e. do you need to find all exercises of a given user, or all users of a given exercise, or both ?

In the first case you will have:

```
public class User{
    private int id;
    private String name;
    List<Exercise> exercises;
}
```

In the second case:

```
public class Exercise{
    private int id;
    private String content;
    private List<User> users;
}
```

And both in the third case.

Take care that bi-directional is more difficult to maintain. You have to do simultaneously:

```
user.getExercises().add(exercise);
exercise.getUsers().add(user);
```

Comment: Great thank you for your answer! It's exactly that i need!